# Add List to Another List on Instantiation C#

Tags: c#, list

How to add a list to another list? Maybe I ask it in a wrong way but bear with me for another minute. I have a list of `KeyValuePair<string, object>` and I want to add another list members into this list. Like this:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>{ new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Screw", "1"),
                                                   new KeyValuePair<string, object>("You", "2"),
                                                   new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Guys", "3")};

var secondList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>{ list, // through error
                                                         new KeyValuePair<string, object>("I'm", "4"),
                                                         new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Going", "5"), 
                                                         new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Home", "6") };
```

As you can guess, error is

> Cannot Convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object>'

It's important for me to add `list` to `secondList` in the instantiation of `secondList`. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: use different constructor `var secondList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>(list){...}`

Comment: @Selvin nice answer, why in the comment? Post as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concat and ToList LINQ-methods:

```
var secondList = list.Concat(new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>{
                                                     new KeyValuePair<string, object>("I'm", "4"),
                                                     new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Going", "5"), 
                                                     new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Home", "6") }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use AddRange method System.Collections.Generic

```
   secondList.AddRange(list)
```

Or  just use  foreach and make the same by your self

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
secondList.Add(item)
}
```

Comment: :))) dude I want this on instantiation, everyone knows how to use foreach or AddRange!

Answer (score 0):

I find that **Concat** is the best solution here
AddRange work but I don't recommand it for you